# android multi marker on image and set event onclick marker (lib SubsamplingScaleImageView)

Tags: android, marker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDpht.jpg)
    package test;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.ImageSource;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import common.PinView;

```
public class RoomFragment extends Fragment{
    PinView imageView;
    LinearLayout layoutFooter;
    List<PointF> pinList = new ArrayList<PointF>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.room_fragment_layout, container, false);
        //footer action bar
        layoutFooter = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.footer_room);
        layoutFooter.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        //End footer action bar

        //image plane and pin
        imageView  = (PinView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plane);
        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.plane));
        imageView.setZoomEnabled(false);
        pinList.add(new PointF(100f, 1200f));
        pinList.add(new PointF(400f, 1200f));
        pinList.add(new PointF(1000f, 1200f));
        imageView.setPins(pinList);
        //imageView.setPin(new PointF(800f, 1200f));

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                layoutFooter.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), motionEvent.getX() + " | " + motionEvent.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    layoutFooter.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                }
                imageView.setPin(new PointF(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY()));

                return false;
            }
        });
        //End image plane and pin
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

}

package common;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView;

import java.util.List;

import product.dm.com.dm.R;


public class PinView extends SubsamplingScaleImageView {

    private PointF sPin;
    private Bitmap pin;
    private List<PointF> pinList;

    public PinView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PinView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        initialise();
    }

    public void setPin(PointF sPin) {
        this.sPin = sPin;
        initialise();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setPins(List<PointF> pinList){
        this.pinList = pinList;
        initialise();
    }

    public PointF getPin() {
        return sPin;
    }

    private void initialise() {
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        pin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin_red);
        float w = (density/420f) * pin.getWidth();
        float h = (density/420f) * pin.getHeight();
        pin = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pin, (int)w, (int)h, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        if (!isReady()) {
            return;
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        if (sPin != null && pin != null) {

            PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(sPin);
            float vX = vPin.x - (pin.getWidth()/2);
            float vY = vPin.y - pin.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(pin, vX, vY, paint);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<pinList.size();i++){
            Paint paints = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(pinList.get(i));
            float vX = vPin.x - (pin.getWidth()/2);
            float vY = vPin.y - pin.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(pin, vX, vY, paints);
        }

    }

}
```